# I can not parse a certain value from json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I wrote a parser that gave me the desired id, but now the view of the JSON-response has changed and the parser does not work, I can not understand how to get this id now
i have this code:

```
  \"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",
  \"result\":{
  \"s\":[
 {
  \"n\":\"@Лицо\",
  \"t\":\"Идентификатор\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"Фамилия\",
  \"t\":\"Строка\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"Имя\",
  \"t\":\"Строка\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"Отчество\",
  \"t\":\"Строка\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"Подразделение\",
  \"t\":\"Строка\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"ФИО\",
  \"t\":\"Строка\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"ИдПодразделения\",
  \"t\":\"Число целое\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"ФотоМини\",
  \"t\":\"Число целое\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"ФотоБольшое\",
  \"t\":\"Число целое\"
 },
 {
  \"n\":\"ИдДолжности\",
  \"t\":\"Число целое\"
 }
  ],
  \"f\":0,
  \"d\":[
  [
  22151885
  ],
  \"Прёсто\",
  \"Руководитель\",
  \"Предприятия\",
  \"Бухгалтерия\",
  \"Прёсто Руководитель Предприятия\",
  23077965,
  64349,
  64685,
  3051
  ],
  \"_type\":\"record\"
  },
  \"id\":1,
  \"protocol\":5
  }
```

I'm trying to get the value "@Лицо"

this my parser

```
struct Profile { 

    var ID: String? 

    var surname: String? 

} 

class ProfileBuilder : Builder { 

    typealias Element = Profile 

    var profile: Profile? 

    func setValue(property: String, value: Any) -> Self { 

        switch property { 

        case "@Лицо": 

            profile!.ID = value as? String 

        default: 

            // do nothing 

            break 

        } 

        return self 

    } 

    func build() -> Profile { 

        return profile! 

    } 



    func reset() { 

        profile = Profile() 

    } 

} 



 func parseRecord<B: Builder>(result: [String: Any], builder: B) throws -> B.Element { 

    let type = result["_type"] as! String 

    if(type == "record") { 

            let s = result["s"] as! [[String: Any]] 

            let d = result["d"] as! [Any] 

            builder.reset() 

            for (index, property) in s.enumerated() { 

            let propertyName = property["n"] as! String 

            builder.setValue(property: propertyName, value: d[index]) 

        } 

        return builder.build() 

        } 



            else { 

                throw RuntimeError("Error deserializing JSON: Json is not Record type") 



        } 

    } 

let profile = self.parseResponse(data: dataProfile!) { (result) in 

                return try self.parseRecord(result: result, builder: ProfileBuilder()) 

            } 

            switch profile { 

            case .Result(let profile): 



                print(profile.ID) 

              //  self.PersonalProfile = profile.ID 

                   print(self.PersonalProfile) 





            case .Error(let error): 



                print(error) 



                } 

            return 

            }
```

where the parser does not work. perhaps it's worth adding one more condition to the parser. Please help and explain what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you post more nicely formatted json? Also, can you use codable for parsing json, or you want to go with above solution?

Comment: i have to go with above solution. I post formatted json

Comment: In this example json value of @Лицо is 22151885?

Comment: yes, @Лицо = 22151885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this part of `ProfileBuilder`:

```
case "@Лицо": 
    profile!.ID = value as? String
```

In your example json, the value for @Лицо is array of one integer, so `value as? String` will fail. I can not run your parser because of some missing parts, so can you try this:

```
case "@Лицо":
    profile!.ID = String((value as? [Int]).first!)
```

And let me know if it works. If it is not, try to provide some more descriptive error message.